pgrep matches undesired patterns
This is the beginning of a script for determining whether to run tmux, it has been modified for debugging purposes:
(no tmux instance is ever running in this test example)
#!/bin/bash -x

if  [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
    echo "We are inside tmux"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $(pgrep -c tmux) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "joining tmux session"
    tmux a
        exit 0
fi

bash

Script run on terminal 1:
alacritty -e ~/tmux.sh
Output on terminal 2:
+ [[ -n '' ]]
++ pgrep -c tmux
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'joining tmux session'
joining tmux session
+ tmux a
no sessions
+ bash
[user@hostname ~]$ pgrep -a tmux
27220 /bin/bash -x /home/user/tmux.sh

I expected the condition to turn false, [[ 0 -ne 0 ]], pgrep should not(?) recognize /bin/bash -x /home/user/tmux.sh since I'm looking for a tmux process, not the string tmux as some process parameter.
Moreover, if on a terminal I run vim ~/tmux.sh, and pgrep -c tmux on another, it returns 0 (while no tmux instance running). So this kind of behavior does not seems to be consistent.
Why I'm getting different results?
Thanks.
Update 1, System info:
alacritty 0.13.2 (bb8ea18e)
bash 5.2.26(1)-release
pgrep from procps-ng 4.0.4
archlinux
Update 2:
It is worth noting that when the script is run with sh/bash, pgrep behaves as expected. It is only when run through alacritty -e ~/tmux.sh that this confusing behavior arises.
Update 3: Also happens when run from a foot or xterm terminal foot ~/tmux.sh.
Update 4:
video

I'm having trouble reproducing your error. What version of pgrep are you using? What is your OS? Specifically with pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.17 your test line of pgrep -a tmux returns nothing. You can try maybe pgrep -c ^tmux, but maybe that will also depend on the version?

note value of cat /proc/$(pgrep tmux.sh)/comm

as workaround you could try if pidof tmux >&- instead of your pgrep test

It is worth noting that when the script is run with sh/bash, pgrep behaves as expected. It is only when run through alacritty -e ~/tmux.sh that this confusing behavior arises.

@jhnc, ...aside: I'd suggest making a habit of >/dev/null instead of >&- -- you don't want a failed write to stdout to return a falsey result by way of error reporting when the check would otherwise be true.

@simbioz, have you considered using tmux's capabilities for listing active sessions? That way you can check not just whether there's a copy of tmux running anywhere else on the same machine, but specifically whether there's a tmux session with a given name and avoid pgrep giving you incorrect results.

That is all to say, I'd argue that best-practice use of tmux (with named sessions and possibly named sockets, both of which you can check for separate from the presence of a tmux process itself) would leave you with no reason to use pgrep in the first place, mooting this question.

The confusion arises because behind the scenes, obscure things happen when one attempts to execute a text file (ie. a file that is not a binary executable). Additionally, the output of pgrep -a regex may not be the string it used to search for the match.

Processes are generally invoked by execve(2). Its manpage notes:


The process name, as set by prctl(2) PR_SET_NAME (and  displayed  by ps -o comm), is reset to the name of the new executable file


Text files are not directly executable; When one attempts to run a text file, behind the scenes the kernel notices that the start of the file is not the normal magic string that indicates a program (typically E L F \002 \001 \001 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0).

If the kernel sees the file starts with # !, it splits the remainder of the first line into two and tries to execute the first part (the interpreter), passing as arguments the second part (often empty, or a flag telling the interpreter to expect a script), and the original process name (typically used by the interpreter as the filename of the script it should run).
The kernel does not reset the ps comm value.


pgrep regex tries to match a regular expression against the "process name" (ps comm value).

This can be confusing in presence of processes invoked as above, if one expects that "process name" should be the name of the interpreter (as pgrep -a regex and the pgrep manpage could lead one to believe is the case).



I don't know Rust so can't follow the alacritty source code but running under strace, I see that alacritty -e ./myscript does eventually do execve("./myscript", [...]).

As an example, here is a bash script that invokes a Perl script that resets its process name. See the confusion that results when searching for it with pgrep. Note the different values of /proc/#pid/exe, /proc/#pid/comm and /proc/#pid/cmdline:
tester:
#!/bin/bash

cat >myscript <<'EOD'
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Linux::Prctl(set_name);
sleep 1;
set_name("gotcha!");
sleep 3;
EOD

chmod +x myscript

myinfo()(
    echo
    echo exe:
    ls -l /proc/$!/exe
    echo ---
    echo comm:
    cat /proc/$!/comm
    echo ---
    echo cmdline:
    tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$!/cmdline
    echo ----
    echo pgrep -a myscript:
    pgrep -a myscript
    echo ----
    echo pgrep -a gotcha:
    pgrep -a gotcha
    echo
)

./myscript &
echo "=== (directly) before ==="
myinfo
sleep 2
echo "=== (directly) after ==="
myinfo

sleep 5

/usr/bin/perl ./myscript &
echo "=== (indirectly) before ==="
myinfo
sleep 2
echo "=== (indirectly) after ==="
myinfo

=== (directly) before ===

exe:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jhnc jhnc 0 Apr 13 18:50 /proc/252563/exe -> /usr/bin/perl
---
comm:
myscript
---
cmdline:
/usr/bin/perl
./myscript
----
pgrep -a myscript:
252563 /usr/bin/perl ./myscript
----
pgrep -a gotcha:

=== (directly) after ===

exe:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jhnc jhnc 0 Apr 13 18:50 /proc/252563/exe -> /usr/bin/perl
---
comm:
gotcha!
---
cmdline:
/usr/bin/perl
./myscript
----
pgrep -a myscript:
----
pgrep -a gotcha:
252563 /usr/bin/perl ./myscript

=== (indirectly) before ===

exe:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jhnc jhnc 0 Apr 13 18:50 /proc/252582/exe -> /usr/bin/perl
---
comm:
perl
---
cmdline:
/usr/bin/perl
./myscript
----
pgrep -a myscript:
----
pgrep -a gotcha:

=== (indirectly) after ===

exe:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jhnc jhnc 0 Apr 13 18:50 /proc/252582/exe -> /usr/bin/perl
---
comm:
gotcha!
---
cmdline:
/usr/bin/perl
./myscript
----
pgrep -a myscript:
----
pgrep -a gotcha:
252582 /usr/bin/perl ./myscript


summary:




directly before
directly after
indirectly before
indirectly after




/proc/#pid/comm
myscript
gotcha!
perl
gotcha!


pgrep -a myscript
found
not found
not found
not found


pgrep -a gotcha
not found
found
not found
found



/proc/#pid/exe and /proc/#pid/cmdline don't change.
When pgrep -a succeeds it always outputs cmdline (not the comm value).

These tests were run against the procps-3.3.17 version of pgrep in Ubuntu 22.04. I don't know if behaviour in newer versions of procps has changed; the source code looks rather different.

I could not reproduce your issue matching tmux in the script name or anything other than tmux.
As suggested by @jhnc using pidof is a better option to match process name, especially with the -q switch that will save both running an extra sub-shell and performing an arithmetic comparison.
Here is your script rewritten using POSIX shell grammar and pidof:
#!/usr/bin/env sh

#set -x # Uncomment for debug

if  [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' 'We are inside tmux' >&2
    exit 1
fi

if pidof -q tmux; then
    printf '%s\n' 'joining tmux session'
    tmux a
    exit 0
fi


As a wise man commented below it says in the pgrep manpage:

The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.

This made you assume (quite understandably) that the process running is /bin/bash, however, if you run a short test you can see that this is not the case.
If we create a test script called test.sh that looks like this:
#!/bin/bash -x

ps
echo "Current PID is $$"
ps -p $$
pgrep "test"

And if we then run chmod +x test.sh we can run the script twice, once with bash, and once without, and see the result:
user@machine:/tmp$ /tmp/test.sh
+ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 685214 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
 737744 pts/6    00:00:00 test.sh
 737745 pts/6    00:00:00 ps
+ echo 'Current PID is 737744'
Current PID is 737744
+ ps -p 737744
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 737744 pts/6    00:00:00 test.sh
+ pgrep 737744
+ pgrep test
737744

user@machine:/tmp$ bash /tmp/test.sh 
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 685214 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
 737749 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
 737750 pts/6    00:00:00 ps
Current PID is 737749
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 737749 pts/6    00:00:00 bash


If we want to go a bit deeper we can look in the source code for pgrep here where we can see in library/include/readproc.h that they use /proc/#/cmdline so we can now test that.
We'll create a test2.sh file:
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "Current PID is $$"
pgrep -a "test"
echo "/proc/$$/cmdline is $(cat /proc/$$/cmdline)"


And after running chmod +x test2.sh we do both test2.sh and bash test2.sh and see:
user@machine:/tmp/procps$ /tmp/test2.sh
+ echo 'Current PID is 10085'
Current PID is 10085
+ pgrep -a test
10085 /bin/bash -x /tmp/test2.sh
++ cat /proc/10085/cmdline
/tmp/test2.sh: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
+ echo '/proc/10085/cmdline is /bin/bash-x/tmp/test2.sh'
/proc/10085/cmdline is /bin/bash-x/tmp/test2.sh

user@machine:/tmp/procps$ bash /tmp/test2.sh
Current PID is 10089
/tmp/test2.sh: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
/proc/10089/cmdline is bash/tmp/test2.sh



So we see that pgrep absolutely should find /home/user/tmux.sh. The pattern you are looking for is tmux, which is a substring of /home/user/tmux.sh.
The better way to solve this (IMO), would be to exclude the PID of the running script like so:
CURR_PID=$$

if [[ $(pgrep -a tmux | grep -cv $CURR_PID) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "joining tmux session"
    tmux a
        exit 0
fi

This uses the fact the $$ variable to get the current PID and remove only it.
Or
You can simply replace the line:
if [[ $(pgrep -c tmux) -ne 0 ]]; then

with
if [[ $(pgrep -v "tmux.sh" | pgrep -c tmux) -ne 0 ]]; then

or maybe even
if [[ $(pgrep -v "sh$" | pgrep -c tmux) -ne 0 ]]; then

Or anything else that will remove the script from seeing itself.
You could simply change the name of the script to not include tmux.
You could also simply change the file name.

I think you've misunderstood the question. As pointed out in pgrep(1), the "pattern is normally only matched against the process name". What is the process name in /bin/bash -x /home/user/tmux.sh? If it includes the arguments, when why is there a -f option?

@jhnc, thanks, I think I've got it now. Better?

@CharlesDuffy, you think this is a bug report?

Eh, if it's a missing feature (a case where excluding parents is only available on some implementations but not others) then it's not a bug report; I'm rechecking the documentation.

it's much more obscure; I'm hoping someone else will write up an answer. basically, the "process name" is set by the execve() call. but text files can't be run directly. so behind the scenes the kernel notices the #! path and invokes the appropriate interpreter. but it doesn't change the ps comm value

@CharlesDuffy it's not a pgrep issue, per se

@jhnc, isn't /proc/#pid/exe a symlink to the binary? That has to be placed there after the terminal has decided what the command is no? That should not be relevant then, or am I missing something? BTW, you're right, it uses /proc/#/cmdline as a source. Updated again. Also, thanks, I'm learning quite a bit here!

I believe pgrep actually uses task.cmd in this situation, rather than cmdline. I'm not entirely sure what it is, but it seems to be the ps comm value

@jhnc, what makes you say that? Both in your answer and in mine, the output for pgrep -a is identical to cmdline with spaces, and in the source code we see in src/prgep.c that task_cmdline = PIDS_GETSTR(CMDLINE); There are other references to cmdline in the code there too.

not what it outputs, what it searches for; note the output in my answer when searching for "gotcha" - which does not appear anywhere in cmdline
